# How to make this select tag looks like like on chrome for safari.?

Tags: html, css

```css
#test {
    border:0px;
    outline:0px;
    color: #696969;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<select id="test">
<option>Test1</option>  
<option>Test1</option>
<option>Test1</option>
<option>Test1</option>
</select>
```

The background looks a little different between chrome and safari, how to make it looks same like on chrome when I open it on safari?

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate browser specific styling of select menus you can use the JQuery selectmenu plugin.

https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/